# Filtering through several SQL searches to build a single array - need pointers

Tags: php, sql, arrays, explode

I'm new to web developing.

This is part of a phone service, and I'm trying to filter through 3 different arrays that are filled with strings from three database searches: $sfaa, $sfipc, and $sfuaa. I have to filter the three database arrays to locate available customer service agents. The output would be an array filled with the IVR_Number to dial.

Heres an example of the string: "'Id', 'IVR_Number', 'Market_Id'"

I have to explode the string in order to get my data from each value in the arrays. Then based on a one-to-many id in each string I have to check if the id from $sfaa is in $sfipc or $sfuaa. If not then I have to build an array with the filtered records, from there I have to locate a value from the exploded string in $sfaa that belongs to that id. I wrote the following code but theres got to be an easier way?? I hope.... The client has to wait for these results before moving forward. There is usually only 10 or 15 records.

This code works I'm just wondering if there is an easier way to do this

Any tips

```
// formalua needed to filter above results and fill $aadl array
        // explode each active agent array
        $activeagentsfec=0;
        $aaivra= array();
        $aaida= array();
        foreach ($sfaa as $aavalue)
        {
            ${'aadetails'.$activeagentsfec} = explode("'",$aavalue);
            ${'aaivr'.$activeagentsfec} = ${'aadetails'.$activeagentsfec}[5];
            ${'aaid'.$activeagentsfec} = ${'aadetails'.$activeagentsfec}[1];
            array_push($aaivra, ${'aaivr'.$activeagentsfec});
            array_push($aaida,${'aaid'.$activeagentsfec});
            $activeagentsfec++;
        }
        // explode each inprogress call array
            $activecallsfec=0;
            $actida= array();
            $acfida= array();
        foreach ($sfipc as $acvalue)
        {
            ${'acdetails'.$activecallsfec} = explode("'",$acvalue);
            ${'actid'.$activecallsfec} = ${'acdetails'.$activecallsfec}[5];
            ${'acfid'.$activecallsfec} = ${'acdetails'.$activecallsfec}[7];
            array_push($actida, ${'actid'.$activecallsfec});
            array_push($acfida, ${'acfid'.$activecallsfec});
            $activecallsfec++;
        }
        // explode each unvailable agent
            $unavailableagentsfec=0;
            $uaaida= array();
        foreach ($sfuaa as $uavalue)
        {
            ${'uadetails'.$unavailableagentsfec} = explode("'",$uavalue);
            ${'uaaid'.$unavailableagentsfec} = ${'uadetails'.$unavailableagentsfec}[3];
            array_push($uaaida, ${'uaaid'.$unavailableagentsfec});
            $unavailableagentsfec++;
        } 
        // create available agent array by id
        $aaafec=0;
        $aada= array();
        foreach ($aaida as $aaidavalue)
        {
            if (in_array($aaidavalue,$actida,true))
            $aaafec++;
            elseif(in_array($aaidavalue,$acfida,true))
            $aaafec++;
            elseif(in_array($aaidavalue,$uaaida,true))
            $aaafec++;
            else
            array_push($aada, $aaidavalue);
        }
        // available agent arry by ivr
        $aadl= array();
        foreach ($aada as $aadavalue)
        {
            $aaaivrsv= array_search($aadavalue,$aaida,true);
            array_push($aadl,$aaivra[$aaaivrsv]);
        }
```

Comment: It might help to describe what the problem is and what you are hoping to achieve with the code above.

Comment: Can you give an example of the values of $sfaa, $sfipc, and $sfuaa - so we can follow why you explode the data in that way...

Comment: Also (this may be out of turn, but...) why return your database data as strings, to then parse them again? Wouldn't it be easier as a 2-D array, or a handle to a query result?

Comment: Yes, I agree with @boisvert, you are trying to do work outside the database which is better done in the database. Why get three lists from the database then try to match them in PHP? Just match them in SQL and get the final result in PHP.

Comment: @boisvert and @Ben The results from the database are from an outside service. So I don't have control over the way the results come in. Heres an example of the string `"'Id', 'IVR_Number', 'Market_Id'"` @pharalia This is part of a phone service. I need an array filled with the IVR_Number to dial. I have to filter the three database arrays to locate available customer service agents. This code works I'm just wondering if there is an easier way to do this. I hope this helps clear things up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you were saying in the comments, I'll try to give you some useful thoughts...

- You carry out much the same process to parse $sfaa, $sfipc, and $sfuaa - explode, get certain columns. If you had some way to abstract that process, with a generic function for the parsing, that returns the data in a better format, called three times on each array, you'd see better through your code.
- In the same way, your process is tightly coupled to the current state of the data - e.g. `${'acdetails'.$activecallsfec}[5];` is your fifth item today, but will it always be? Something generic, where you seek an column by name, might save you a lot of trouble...
- finally, when merging data, if the data is sorted before hand the merge can be a lot quicker - seeking N items in a list of M, with an unsorted list takes O(n*m) operations, but if both are sorted it's O(min(m,n)).

I've taken the time to go through your code... Unless you're usign some of its variables elsewhere, here is a shorter equivalent:

```
// formula needed to filter above results and fill $aadl array
   // explode each active agent array
   $aaivra= array();
   $aaida= array();
   foreach ($sfaa as $aavalue)
   {
      $a = explode("'",$aavalue);
      array_push($aaivra, $a[5]);
      array_push($aaida,$a[1]);
   }
   // explode each inprogress call array
   $actida= array();
   $acfida= array();
   foreach ($sfipc as $acvalue)
   {
      $a = explode("'",$acvalue);
      array_push($actida, $a[5]);
      array_push($acfida, $a[7]);
   }
   // explode each unvailable agent
   $uaaida= array();
   foreach ($sfuaa as $uavalue)
   {
      $a= explode("'",$uavalue);
      array_push($uaaida, $a[3]);
   } 
   // create available agent array by id
   $aada= array();
   foreach ($aaida as $aaidavalue)
   {
      if (!in_array($aaidavalue,$actida,true) &&
          !in_array($aaidavalue,$acfida,true) &&
          !in_array($aaidavalue,$uaaida,true))
         array_push($aada, $aaidavalue);
   }
   // available agent arry by ivr
   $aadl= array();
   foreach ($aada as $aadavalue)
   {
      $aaaivrsv= array_search($aadavalue,$aaida,true);
      array_push($aadl,$aaivra[$aaaivrsv]);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @boisvert that will work a lot better. I do need to use the values later on but it depends on the flow of the IVR system. Plus it will be different values in the string that I will need. So I'll run something similar to get those values if needed. Thanks again for the help.